# BackgroundDownloader Class and SSL

Tags: ssl, windows-8, download, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

i have next problem:

I have tried to use BackgroundDownloader Class to download files from server, but it didn't download them because server needs certificate. ( When i downloaded data from any other URL, from internet - all worked fine, that means my code was correct).

So, currently i'm getting data from server using HTTPClient and adding certificate, but this is unstable method, because if app suspends - there will be problems.

**So the question is, is there a way to use BackgroundDownloader Class with certificate?**

Comment: Do you mean client certificate? How do you set the certificate in the WebClient?

Comment: I'm sorry, mistaken, HTTP client